# Crear un objeto apartir de 2 array

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, javascript-objeto

Lo que quiero es crear un objeto que sus keys sean el contenido del primer array, y el valor sea el contenido del segundo array.

```javascript
const keys = [
     "Código inmueble",
     "Barrio común",
     "Precio (Desde/Hasta)",
     "Área construida (Desde/Hasta)",
     "Área privada (Desde/Hasta)",
     "Estado",
     "Fecha estimada de entrega"
]

const values = [
     "5503-C00001-06",
     "CEDRITOS", 
     "$345.000.000 / $345.000.000",
     "54.25 m² / 56.44 m²",
     "47 m² / 50.39 m²",
     "Para Estrenar",
     "06-2020"
]
```

Lo que quiero es algo así:

```javascript
const obj = {
     "Código inmueble": "5503-C00001-06",
     "Barrio común": "CEDRITOS", 
     "Precio (Desde/Hasta)": "$345.000.000 / $345.000.000",
     "Área construida (Desde/Hasta)":"54.25 m² / 56.44 m²",
     "Área privada (Desde/Hasta)": "47 m² / 50.39 m²",
     "Estado": "Para Estrenar",
     "Fecha estimada de entrega":"06-2020"
}
```

Cómo podria obtener este resultado?

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta es bastante clara pero te recomiendo incluir un [mcve] en el que muestres el esfuerzo que has hecho hasta el momento y enfocar tus dudas y/o preguntas con respecto a ese ejemplo. Como sugerencia sencilla puedo decirte que si ambos arrays tienen la misma longitud y las posiciones son correspondientes en ambos, puedes usar un `for` y dentro asignar la propiedad valor como si de un array se tratara.

Answer (score 1):

La solución:

```javascript
    const obj = {}
    let counter = 0
    for (let key of keys) { 
      obj[key] = values[counter]
      counter++
    }
```